# Adding dependencies in intelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have an android project and an instruction to add this
    `compile 'com.github.claucookie.miniequalizer:library:1.0.0'`

as a dependency in the project.
I dont know the right options to use after i go to the project structure of the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Step 1:

For adding dependency go to applevel gradle file

[image]

#### Step 2:

Add `compile 'com.github.claucookie.miniequalizer:library:1.0.0'` in dependency,.after last line before`}`
[image]

ie. I have added your dependency shown below

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    compile 'com.github.claucookie.miniequalizer:library:1.0.0'
}
```

#### Step 3:

After this click on sync Gradle [image].

Answer (score 2):

in your `project -->gradle Scripts--> build.gradle (Module:App)`

add the dependency like:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rafsan.practice"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.claucookie.miniequalizer:library:1.0.0'   //add the dependency here
}
```